# Show that $\varphi(y)\leq Cf(y)$ for all $y\in X$, for some constant $C>0$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, proof-explanation

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. Let $f:X\to (0,\infty)$ be continuous, and let $\varphi$ be a non-negative function belonging to $C_c(X)$. I read in a proof that tries to show that $\varphi(y)\leq Cf(y)$ for all $y\in X$, for some $C>0$.

It begins with

> For any $x\in \textrm{supp} \varphi$ there exists a constant $c_x>0$ such that $\varphi(x)<c_xf(x)$. $\quad$ (*)

Where does the existence come from?

> This inequality (*) subsists in an open neighborhood $V_x$ of $x$.

Why does it hold? Is it due to continuity of $\varphi,f$? Last question

> The open sets $V_x$, $x\in \textrm{supp}\varphi$ cover $\textrm{supp} \varphi$. By compactness of $\textrm{supp}\varphi$ we have $\textrm{supp}\varphi\subseteq V_{x_1}\cup \dots V_{x_n}$ for certain points $x_1,\dots, x_n\in \textrm{supp}\varphi$.

Is this due to the Borel's coverings theorem? Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question: Take $c_x=\frac {\phi (x)} {f(x)}$.

Second question: This follows by continuity. $c_cf-\phi$ is a continuous function which is positive  value at $x$ so it is  postive in some neighborhood.

Third question: This is just definition of compacteness: Every open cover of a compact set has a finite subcover.

Answer (score 1):

(1) The existence of $c_x$ just comes from choosing any real number larger than $\varphi(x)/f(x)$.

(2) Yes, this is due to the fact that $\varphi(x)/f(x)$ is continuous.

(3) More directly, the existence of an open subcover comes directly from the definition of compactness.

Comment: [Kavi Rama Murthy beat me by twenty seconds](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3816790/16078) :D

Comment: "choosing any real number larger than $\phi(x)/f(x)$". This can only happen if $\phi(x)/f(x)$ is bounded above, right? That's can be seen because $0<\phi(x)/f(x)\leq \phi(x)$ and $\phi$ is compact supported, or ... ?